# How to install and include a library to my C compiler?

Tags: c, compilation

I am using Debian 11

I am trying to reproduce strlcpy.

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <string.h>
  3 #include <stdlib.h>
  4 
  5 unsigned int ft_strlcpy(char *dest, char *src, unsigned int size)
  6 {
  7   unsigned int i;
  8 
  9   i = 0;
 10   while (src[i] && i < size)
 11   {
 12     dest[i] = src[i];
 13     i++;
 14   }
 15   dest[i] = '\0';
 16   while (src[i])
 17     i++;
 18   return (i);
 19 }
 20 
 21 int main()
 22 {
 23   unsigned int i;
 24   char *dest1 = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
 25   char *dest2 = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
 26 
 27   i = 0;
 28   while (i < 26)
 29   {
 30     printf("%d ", ft_strlcpy(dest1, "hello my name is marcel", i));
 31     printf("%s\n", dest1);
 32     printf("%ld ", strlcpy(dest2, "hello my name is marcel", i));
 33     printf("%s\n", dest2);
 34     i++;
 35   }
 36   free(dest1);
 37   free(dest2);
 38   return (0);
 39 }
```

However, I get this message when I compile my code:

```
ft_strlcpy.c: In function ‘main’:
ft_strlcpy.c:32:18: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strlcpy’; did you mean ‘strncpy’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   32 |   printf("%ld ", strlcpy(dest2, "hello my name is marcel", i));
      |                  ^~~~~~~
      |                  strncpy
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccukR8g6.o: in function `main':
ft_strlcpy.c:(.text+0xf0): undefined reference to `strlcpy'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: ft_strlcpy] Error 1
```

I have no idea how to include libbsd or use pkgconf.
I have tried for a couple of hours, but I couldn't find the solution.

If someone could redirect me to a manual or explain the concepts, that would be great.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The `strlcpy` function is included in the [BSD libc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library#BSD_libc), a superset (extended version) of the [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) standard library for [BSD operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_BSD_operating_systems). For it to be recognized by the compiler you have to first install the library through your package manager, the name of which will be either `libbsd`, `libbsd-dev` or `libbsd-devel` depending on whether your distribution uses seperate development libraries or not, and than include it as `<bsd/string.h>`. You can then compile it with (assuming you use GCC) `gcc <your-filename>.c -lbsd`, specifying the library to be [linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29). I wouldn't recommended using BSD functions outside of BSD specific software due to portability issues (POSIX incompliences).

Comment: I just reread your question and noticed that you did mention you use Debian, as far as I can tell apt doesn't have seperate development packages, so the package name will be simply `libbsd`.